# Equations involving quasiperfect numbers: a first search of odd solutions for this type of equations or well succinct reasonings about these

Tags: nt.number-theory, counterexamples, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

In this post we study the following equations that involve quasiperfect numbers, denoted as $x$, that are integers such that the sum of all its positive divisors is equals to $2x+1$, and certain multiplicative functions These are the sum of divisors function $\sum_{1\leq d \mid n}d$ denoted as $\sigma(n)$, the Euler's totient function $\varphi(n)$ and the product of distinct prime numbers dividing an integer $n>1$ that is denoted  $$\operatorname{rad}(n)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\p\text{ prime}}}p\,.$$
The spirit of the post was to create equations involving these arithmetic functions, and now I ask if you can to find odd solutions of these equations (since I think that ask about what work can be done about these equations is very difficult to solve, I prefer in this ocassion ask about possible odd solutions, thus I present the following very similar equations/questions in which you can to find an odd solution you as a counterexample or well discuss from a theoretical/heuristic point of view if one can to hope odd solutions of our equations).

Thus a characterization of quasiperfect numbers is given as $$\sigma(x)=2x+1,$$

you can see for example the Wikipedia with title [*Quasiperfect number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiperfect_number) as a reference for this post.

**Fact.** *If* $x$ *is a quasiperfect number then the following identities are satisfied* $$\varphi(x^{\sigma(x)}\sigma(x)^x)=x^{2x}(2x+1)^{x-1}\varphi(x)\varphi(2x+1),\tag{1}$$
$$\sigma(x^{\sigma(x)}\sigma(x)^x)=\sigma\left(x^{2x+1}\right)\sigma((2x+1)^x)\tag{2}$$
*and* $$\operatorname{rad}\left(\frac{\varphi(x^{\sigma(x)}\sigma(x)^x)}{\varphi(x(2x+1))}\right)=\operatorname{rad}(x)\operatorname{rad}(2x+1).\tag{3}$$

As aside remark, one can also multiply by $f(2^{\alpha})$ previous equations, where $\alpha$ is a positive integer and $f(n)$ the corresponding multiplicative function in each identity.

> **Question.** Can you find an odd integer $1\leq X$ satisfying the equation $(1)$, or well the equation $(2)$ or well the equation $(3)$? In other case, if it is possible, explain why one should expect or well should not expect odd solutions for each one or some of the previous equations $(1)$, $(2)$ or $(3)$.  I understand in this ocassion succinct answers, with the purpose to accept an useful answer. **Many thanks.**

I got computational evidence about the following conjecture based on my computation, but due that the integers in previous equations are exponentials I prefer don't add it. In any case I write the conjecture that I've evoked in the second paragraph.

**Conjecture.** *There aren't odd integers* $1\leq X$ *satisfying* $(1)$ *and there aren't odd integers* $1\leq X$ *satisfying* $(2)$. *Similarly, an odd integer* $X\geq 1$ *for which* $\varphi\left(X(2X+1)\right)\mid\varphi\left(X^{\sigma(X)}\sigma(X)^X\right)$ 
*will never satisfy the identity* $(3)$.

---

I think that, now, previous **Conjecture** it is just a speculation, thus if you can add heuristics or claims yourself computational evidence add it as comments. Also I hope not to bore you with this equations, therefore if you have ideas to improve the mathematical content this type of equations add a comment

Comment: Hi, all I think that an interesting question could be study $\operatorname{rad}(x)$ for $x$ a quasiperfect number. I can only to get  obvious statements,  if isn't in the literature feel free to study the question as a professional mathematician.

Comment: Hi, @user142929.  In case you still do not know, V. Siva Rama Prasad and C. Sunitha proved in ([On the prime factors of a quasiperfect number](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-25/NNTDM-25-2-016-021.pdf), Theorem 3.5, page 18) that
$$\operatorname{rad}(x) > \bigg(\frac{1}{2^{1/r} - 1}\bigg)^r$$
where $r = \omega(x)$ is the number of *distinct prime factors* of $x$.  This is in response to your comment above about studying $\operatorname{rad}(x)$ for $x$ a quasiperfect number.

Comment: Using the lower bound in my previous comment together with the bound $r = \omega(x) \geq 7$ (Cohen G. L. & Hagis Jr., P. (1982). Some results concerning quasiperfect numbers, J. Austral. Math. Soc. (Ser.A), 33, 275–286), we obtain
$$\operatorname{rad}(x) > \bigg(\frac{1}{2^{1/7} - 1}\bigg)^7 \approx 7553550.6198,$$
which implies that $\operatorname{rad}(x) \geq 7553551$ since $\operatorname{rad}(x)$ must be an integer.

Comment: Thanks you very much @JoseArnaldoBebita-Dris